# Is there a possibility to have smart flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align a few elements. All the elements are in one div and as the width decreases, at some point the elements won't fit one line anymore. (Overflowing should be avoided)
I am using flexbox to achieve this.
I realised, that whenever the last element doesn't fit the width anymore, it is moved to the next row.
Is there any possibility to make the rows of equal width? Means if I need 2 rows, multiple items are moved to the next row, so that the width of both rows is as similar as possible?
I am adding a codepen with an example. If further clarification is needed please let me know.
https://codepen.io/bvonr/pen/KKvprdg

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
  height: 90px;
}
div {
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.b {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.c {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
}
.d {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.e {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: purple;
}
.f {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: brown;
}
.g {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="f"></div>
  <div class="g"></div>
</div>
<h1>
  If you decrease the width only the grey box will appear in the next line. But the grey and brown boxes together would make a much clearer picture, as their width would more or less equal the width of the oher boxes.
</h1>
```

Comment: No. You will need javascript or media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use nth-child and media queries. This styles give you behavior that you want
from 800 to 1000 screen width

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
  height: 90px;
}
div {
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.b {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.c {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
}
.d {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.e {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: purple;
}
.f {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: brown;
}
.g {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container div:nth-child(-n+3){
    width: 170px;
  }
  .container div:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    width: 320px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="f"></div>
  <div class="g"></div>
</div>
<h1>
  If you decrease the width only the grey box will appear in the next line. But the grey and brown boxes together would make a much clearer picture, as their width would more or less equal the width of the oher boxes.
</h1>
```

Comment: Yeah media queries are an option. I just thought there is something more convenient. Thank you for your help.